# OData Action Get for Short input type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an OData service. In the table in my MS.SQLServer there is no primary key and it has a field that its name is Id and it is smallint. I generated a controller in my OData service and it has two get actions as below :

```
    // GET: odata/BankAccs
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<BankAcc> Get()
    {
        return db.BankAcc;
    }

    // GET: odata/BankAccs(5)
    [Queryable]
    public SingleResult<BankAcc> Get([FromODataUri] short key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(db.BankAcc.Where(bankAcc => bankAcc.Id 
           == key));
    }
```

I installed OData v4 Client Code Generator in my client side to call this service. I call the service with below code :

```
    var bankAccs = container.BankAccs.Where(n => n.Id == 312).Select(x => 
                                      x).ToList();
    var bankAcc = bankAccs.Select(x => x.No).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(bankAcc[0]);
```

When I run my client then I will encounter below error :

> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: 'An error occurred
>   while processing this request.'
>
> Inner Exception        DataServiceClientException:
>   {"error":{"code":"","message":"An error has
>   occurred.","innererror":{"message":"Unknown function
>   'cast'.","type":"System.NotImplementedException","stacktrace":"   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.FilterBinder.BindSingleValueFunctionCallNode(SingleValueFunctionCallNode
>   node)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.FilterBinder.Bind(QueryNode
>   node)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.FilterBinder.BindBinaryOperatorNode(BinaryOperatorNode
>   binaryOperatorNode)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.FilterBinder.Bind(QueryNode
>   node)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.FilterBinder.BindExpression(SingleValueNode
>   expression, RangeVariable rangeVariable, Type elementType)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.FilterBinder.Bind(FilterClause
>   filterClause, Type filterType, IEdmModel model, IAssembliesResolver
>   assembliesResolver, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.ApplyTo(IQueryable
>   query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings, IAssembliesResolver
>   assembliesResolver)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable
>   query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ApplyQuery(IQueryable
>   queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object
>   response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext
>   actionExecutedContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext
>   actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End
>   of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"}}}

I know that the problem is for this smallint in my database and I cannot change it and how can I solve it in my program???

Comment: The SQL Server `smallint` type is equivalent to .net `Int16` and c# `short`.  How is the property `BankAcc.Id` declared? Is it Int16/short or is other type?

Comment: Yes, It is exactly Int16 and short.
As you see in the input of second Get action that scaffolding made is 'short'

Comment: I searched it and found the answer in the address ===>> (https://forums.asp.net/t/1973366.aspx?odata+unknown+function+cast)

In this address said that I must write  (var bankAccs = container.BankAccs.Where(n => n.Id..Equals(312)).Select(x => 
                                      x).ToList();) instead of  (var bankAccs = container.BankAccs.Where(n => n.Id == 312).Select(x => 
                                      x).ToList();) in my client side application.

Comment: Consider answering your own question, it is not only allowed but encouraged.

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem. Do you have any better idea??

Comment: I have added an answer myself, if you add one I will remove mine so you could get the credit. Edit: You could try not to use an integer in the client side declaring a short variable, check the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client application is most likely not providing a `short` but an `int` to the OData layer, raising the error.

You can workaround it querying the data using:

```
var bankAccs = container.BankAccs.Where(n => n.Id..Equals(312)).Select(x => x).ToList();
```

instead of:

```
var bankAccs = container.BankAccs.Where(n => n.Id == 312).Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Source of that info: [odata unknown function cast](https://forums.asp.net/t/1973366.aspx?odata+unknown+function+cast)

I would give a try avoiding the wrong type explicitly:

```
short bankId = 312;
var bankAccs = container.BankAccs.Where(n => n.Id == (short)bankId).Select(x => x).ToList();
```